# how to properly make the firewall block any application by group?

Tags: firewall, group, application

to block the application I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/320008/46437), but like:

```
groupadd nonet
adduser $USER nonet
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner nonet -j REJECT #put at /etc/rc.local

sudo -k iptables --list |grep nonet #to confirm
#REJECT all -- anywhere anywhere owner GID match nonet reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

to test (after reboot):

```
sg nonet "ping www.google.com" #was blocked
sg nonet "google-chrome" #was able to connect, why?
sg nonet "links2" #was able to connect, why?

# showed all properly being on group nonet
ps --forest -A -o pid,ppid,user,group,cmd |egrep "links|chrome"
```

So, it did not work for some applications.
**How is the correct way to let the firewall rule (by group) work for all applications (when using `sg nonet`)?**

ps.: ubuntu 16.04 here